# Pass HTML Form results into GS function

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm *very* new to HTML in general so I'm hoping this comes down to me just missing on some basics.

**Overview**

I'm attempting to build a web page that will allow users to:

1. Define multiple filter criteria at the calendar event level (includes button to "Add Event Filters")
2. Define multiple filters per event (includes button to "Add Filters" inside a given events form entry.
3. Automatically colorize events based on defined filters (the GS/JS piece of this I'm already comfortable with and have a good proof of concept for).
4. Store configurations to update later or add additional events/filters.

I'm using a Google Apps Script / Google Cloud Platform to do this.

**Issue**

I'm trying to figure out how to correctly clone forms, and then pass all the filled-out values to the GS function to process the entries and colorize calendar events. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to pass the FULL results without needing to manually enter the form values. Ideally, I'd parse the entries as JSON first and pass that result into the function.

Example of what I'm hoping to get (or something along these lines):

```
  {
  "Event 1": [{
    "Filter 1": {
      "Filter Field": "Event Title",
      "Filter Operator": "equals",
      "Filter Value": "1 on 1 Meetings"
    },
    "Filter 2": {
      "Filter Field": "Guest Domain",
      "Filter Operator": "contains",
      "Filter Value": "domain.com"
    }
  }],
  "Event 2": [{
    "Filter 1": {
      "Filter Field": "Event Title",
      "Filter Operator": "equals",
      "Filter Value": "1 on 1 Meetings"
    },
    "Filter 2": {
      "Filter Field": "Guest Domain",
      "Filter Operator": "contains",
      "Filter Value": "domain.com"
    }
  }]
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nalloyd2/L9v2jyca/45/) link with what I've got at the moment.

Comment: google.script.run.gsfunctionname(formobj);

Comment: If you are passing dates you will have to convert them to strings due to [parameter restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication?hl=en#parameters_and_return_values)

Comment: While links to external resources might be helpful, questions on this site should be self-contained. If your code on the JSFiddle is too large or have some relevant features only available on that platform add a [mcve] here.

Comment: Also please bear in mind that questions on this site should be specific, meaning they should be about a single issue/problem/concern.